# Setting the value of a PHP session variable to a variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I have created a session variable $_SESSION["email"] and I have set it equal to a variable $email, like this:

```
$_SESSION["email"] =  $email;
```

The problem is I am not able to access this variable in another PHP page. If I do:

```
echo $_SESSION["email"];
```

Nothing gets printed.  I'm beginning to doubt if what I did is actually possible. Where am I going wrong? I have started sessions on both these pages yet I face this problem.

Edit:

I just noticed something. If $email is assigned a value in the first page,

```
echo $_SESSION["email"];
```

Displays the expected value. But in my case,

```
$email = $_POST["email"]
```

whose value I'm receiving from an HTML form.

Comment: Did you use `session_start()` on the other page? When you set session variables and try to use them , you need to write `session_start()`, in each file, best if you do it in the first line of your code.

Comment: Yes I have mentioned clearly that I have started sessions on both these pages

Answer (score -1):

first you need to start session by using

```
session_start();
```

For more information please check PHP documentation :)
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Yes I have clearly mentioned that I have started sessions on both these pages

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by @jonatanrek, session_start() should be first statement in script, make sure it's on the beginning of your script.

You can check running example here https://codetopology.com/php/php-session-how-to-pass-variable-value-from-one-page-to-another/